# Linux wrong path exported. How to recover ~./bashrc file

Tags: bash, recover

While I try to set java path on `~./bashrc` file i exported like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin
export PATH
```

which I guess makes all the other path missing.So it makes me any of the core command like cp not working. I am aware the default `~./bashrc` file will be there on `/etc/skel`. But since none of the common comments working i am not able to copy it. Is there any way we can revert original `~./bashrc`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put something like:

```
PATH=/your/jdk/bin/path:${PATH}
export PATH
```

That way, your path gets *prepended* to the regular `PATH` environment.

And simply log out and log back in to reset your environment.
Or type this:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

or this

```
. /etc/profile
```

to reload a basic environment if you can't get an editor to work right now.

Comment: Since none of the basic commands working i am not able to launch vi editor as well. setting in command prompt is not working either.

Comment: Or if it's `.bashrc` in particular, try `. /etc/skel/.bashrc` from the prompt on many systems.  Notice the dot and the space before the file name.

Answer (score 5):

You can always run commands with absolute paths, like

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc .bashrc
```