# Exiting bash mode in a linux VM

Tags: linux, bash, vi

I was trying to permanently set environmental variables for a linux VM, and I edited the .bashrc file and added two variables there. To see these variables I used the 
`bash
 echo $VARIABLE`

to make sure that I set the variables correctly. Now I can't seem to exit the bash though. I don't know if editing these variables has messed up the system now or what. I used VI to edit the file originally, but now I can't undo the changes with VI or anything because I'm getting an error that `-bash: vi: command not found`.

So my question is, how do I exit bash mode?

Thanks

Comment: So one of the variables you messed around with was the PATH, and you screwed it up. Type the full path to your editor, e.g. `/usr/bin/vi` or `/bin/vi`

Comment: Yes PATH was one of the variables I edited haha. How can I reset it? Thanks

Comment: On many systems, the default `.bashrc` can be reinstalled with `. /etc/skel/.bashrc`.  Notice the lone dot and space before the file name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux wrong path exported. How to recover ~./bashrc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361937/linux-wrong-path-exported-how-to-recover-bashrc-file)

Comment: If this user is not ROOT; then find the echo $PATH by loggig in to some other user & get the appropriate path

Answer (score 0):

So the problem as was found was that I edited the PATH variable which then messed around with the entire shell.

In order to reset this I used the `. /etc/skel/.bashrc` command.

Thanks guys